# HOWTO: Close window command prompt application

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a C# console application, let's say ConsoleApp.exe.
It is executed from command prompt and I pass it some parameters, e.g.:

```
ConsoleApp.exe arg1 arg2 -opt1 option1 -opt2 option2
```

Then application starts, it does some stuff and finally after doing all the stuff I want window command prompt (cmd) from which it is executed to be closed automatically.

I have tried Environment.Exit(0). It finishes application by it does not close cmd window.

So how can I do this programatically?

Comment: Why don't you start the application using a shortcut? You don't have to start it from a command prompt.

Comment: can you show your code.. perhaps you are doing something incorrectly but we can't tell with just the single line of code that you posted.. thanks

Comment: That's not the way its supposed to work, an existing console is really none of your business once your app returns ...

Comment: @AlexK. I need to close the cmd window because one of the arguments passed to the application is a password to connect to a FTP server. Then the application do some things and finishes. Once finished I do not want to keep the cmd window open as it reflect the password passed by parameter, so I need to close it if the user that executes it does not close it because she/he forgets.

Comment: Can't you `@echo off`?

Answer (score 2):

You should not do that. If the program was called from `cmd`, it should not close the command program. This would be really wrong if the user intends to carry on with their work after your program has ran.

You can of course look up the parent process and kill that one when you want to exit your application, but please don't.

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to kill the parent program.
If your app is writing something to the command prompt then start it using a shortcut passing your args to it

```
"c:\path\to\exe\ConsoleApp.exe" arg1 arg2 -opt1 option1 -opt2 option2
```